# Extract data from a list until a specified total is met

Tags: vba, list, excel

I have 2 lists of data that are stacked on top of eachother. These are lists of accounts where I need the total of the top list to be as close as possible to the number specified on the Master sheet in cell I10. I have been doing this manually over the last little while. For example, if I need the sum of all the accounts to be as close to 1 billion as I can get, I start copying and pasting out values from the top list and place them in the bottom list until the sum of the top list is about 1 billion. I originally wrote some vb code that just keeps taking account values from the bottom of list one and places them a the bottom of list 2 until the sum is below 1 billion, but the issue with this was that the last number that gets pulled from list 1 is ridiculously large, so my total is very far under my 1 billion range.

My new approach (which is probably very poor) was to first do as above, then search through the bottom list for smallish values and place them back in the top list until I get fairly close to 1 billion. (I can be over or under 1 billion, but not by an extreme amount) Oh also, my lists are aways changing size.. I.e this needs to be dynamic (and list 2 has the possibility of blank cells)

Below is my first attempt that made my total too small.

If someone can help me figure out how to do this I would be very appreciative.

```
    If Worksheets("Output").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(2) > (Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I10").Value + 0.1) * 1000000 Then
        Do
            Worksheets("Output").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 3)).Cut
            Worksheets("Output").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Loop Until Worksheets("Output").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(2) < (Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I10") + 0.1) * 1000000
    End If
```

Comment: Sort your original list in descending order based on its value. Then keep on picking the items as long as the total is less than total specified.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal would you mind showing me how I would code that. I'm awful with vb code

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I use to find combinations that total to a certain value.

I have it hooked this up to a userform, so just manually provide values for:

MaxSoln = the maximum solutions to be found

TargetVal = the value you want to total to

SearchRange = The range where your values are stored in Excel

```
Option Explicit

Function RealEqual(A, B, Optional Epsilon As Double = 0.00000001)
    RealEqual = Abs(A - B) <= Epsilon
    End Function
Function ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, NewVal, Separator)
    If CurrRslt = "" Then ExtendRslt = NewVal _
    Else ExtendRslt = CurrRslt & Separator & NewVal
    End Function
Sub recursiveMatch(ByVal MaxSoln As Long, ByVal TargetVal, InArr(), _
        ByVal HaveRandomNegatives As Boolean, _
        ByVal CurrIdx As Long, _
        ByVal CurrTotal, ByVal Epsilon As Double, _
        ByRef Rslt(), ByVal CurrRslt As String, ByVal Separator As String)
On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long
    For i = CurrIdx To UBound(InArr)
        If RealEqual(CurrTotal + InArr(i), TargetVal, Epsilon) Then
            Rslt(UBound(Rslt)) = ("Totaled to: " & CombinationFinder.TotalTo.Value) _
                & Separator & ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, InArr(i), Separator)
            If MaxSoln = 0 Then
            Else
                If UBound(Rslt) >= MaxSoln Then Exit Sub
                End If
            ReDim Preserve Rslt(UBound(Rslt) + 1)
        ElseIf IIf(HaveRandomNegatives, False, CurrTotal + InArr(i) > TargetVal + Epsilon) Then
        ElseIf CurrIdx < UBound(InArr) Then
            recursiveMatch MaxSoln, TargetVal, InArr(), HaveRandomNegatives, _
                i + 1, _
                CurrTotal + InArr(i), Epsilon, Rslt(), _
                ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, InArr(i), Separator), _
                Separator
            If MaxSoln <> 0 Then If UBound(Rslt) >= MaxSoln Then Exit Sub
        Else
            'we've run out of possible elements and we _
             still don't have a match
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
Function ArrLen(Arr()) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    ArrLen = UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1
    End Function
Function checkRandomNegatives(Arr) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    i = LBound(Arr)
    Do While Arr(i) < 0 And i < UBound(Arr): i = i + 1: Loop
    If i = UBound(Arr) Then Exit Function
    Do While Arr(i) >= 0 And i < UBound(Arr): i = i + 1: Loop
    checkRandomNegatives = Arr(i) < 0
    End Function
Sub startSearch()
    'The selection should be a single contiguous range in a single column. _
     The first cell indicates the number of solutions wanted.  Specify zero for all. _
     The 2nd cell is the target value. _
     The rest of the cells are the values available for matching. _
     The output is in the column adjacent to the one containing the input data.
    Dim searchrange As Range
    Set searchrange = Range(CombinationFinder.RefRange)

    If Not TypeOf searchrange Is Range Then GoTo ErrXIT
    If searchrange.Areas.Count > 1 Or searchrange.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo ErrXIT
    If searchrange.Rows.Count < 3 Then GoTo ErrXIT

    Dim TargetVal, Rslt(), InArr(), StartTime As Date, MaxSoln As Long, _
        HaveRandomNegatives As Boolean

    MaxSoln = CombinationFinder.Max.Value
    TargetVal = CombinationFinder.TotalTo.Value

    InArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(searchrange)
    HaveRandomNegatives = checkRandomNegatives(InArr)
    If Not HaveRandomNegatives Then
    ElseIf MsgBox("At least 1 negative number is present between positive numbers" _
                & vbNewLine _
            & "It may take a lot longer to search for matches." & vbNewLine _
            & "OK to continue else Cancel", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
        End If

    ReDim Rslt(0)
    recursiveMatch MaxSoln, TargetVal, InArr, HaveRandomNegatives, LBound(InArr), 0, 0.00000001, Rslt, "", ", "
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & ArrLen(Rslt)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rslt)
    Exit Sub
ErrXIT:
    MsgBox "Please select cells in a single column before using this macro" & vbNewLine _
        & "The selection should be a single contiguous range in a single column." & vbNewLine _
        & "The first cell indicates the number of solutions wanted.  Specify zero for all." & vbNewLine _
        & "The 2nd cell is the target value." & vbNewLine _
        & "The rest of the cells are the values available for matching." & vbNewLine _
        & "The output is in the column adjacent to the one containing the input data."
    End Sub
```